# How can I leverage artificial intelligence and virtual reality to create intelligent automatic story generation?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, natural-language-understanding, natural-language-generation, story-generation

How can I leverage artificial intelligence and virtual reality to create intelligent automatic story generation?

My idea is to come up with a system that is empowering the user’s imagination to create and experience stories that engage and immerse them. So they can have the control over the story creation/narrative?

A system that could enable the following use cases:

1. We sit down in our entertainment room. Select a genre from a menu. Pick the character types for the cast. Decide on a generic plot or give the system the option of picking a random choice. Sit back and enjoy.
2. Let's say, I want to watch a sci-fi movie set in Paris with Marlon Brando and Jim Carrey. Then the system instantly generates such a movie.

It has come to my attention that SoarTech developed a pattern-of-life capability for the U.S. Army Simulation: [Agent-based Patterns of Life for Virtual Environments](https://youtu.be/CitevFwa3TE).

That the University of Twente in the Netherlands has been working on a project called the [Virtual Storyteller](http://www.virtualstoryteller.info/).

Here is a research paper entitled [The automatic generation of narratives](http://wwwhome.cs.utwente.nl/%7Etheune/PUBS/Narrator-final-clin17.pdf).

And more recently that IBM has developed a [speech recognition sandbox](https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/create-a-virtual-reality-speech-sandbox/).

I know that the answer probably requires tech, AI, speech, VR and AR, and Watson integration specialists, but any help is welcome.

Watson probably won't be a necessary component of the solution, as long it is an efficient voice recognition software with speech to animation features.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67014/discussion-on-question-by-user108180-automatic-story-generator).

Answer (score 1):

The VR and computer speech aspects are entirely corollary.  Adding them in would be relatively trivial in comparison to creating an algorithm that can dynamically generate stories *of interest to humans.*  Essentially, aesthetic components not related to story structure (images, sounds, speech) are "window dressings".

A story generation algorithm would have to focus on the structural elements of storytelling, possibly in conjunction with human-user reactions, and generate narratives narratives dynamically.

Such a system would be validated by human reaction to the stories, and the validation would not require graphics, sounds or speech.  Think of a movie or video game with a story as the expressions of stories that originally had textual form.

Game theory could certainly be applied to this process--creation of narrative in particular utilizes game theoretic concepts, consciously or unconsciously, in terms of strategies to engage reader/viewers and provide "emotional payoffs".

It should certainly be possible to develop an algorithm with these capabilities, even where the algorithm doesn't not really "understand" the content it is generation.

A similar endeavor might be found in [Cameron Browne](http://www.cameronius.com/)'s work on algorithms that can create simple, combinatorial games of interest to humans: [Evolutionary Game Design](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.421.3450&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

It's important to note that the game created by Ludi are based on pre-existing mechanics, and algorithms don't yet have the capability to make profound leaps in the way that human game designers can. *(In other words, it will likely be a very long time before an algorithm can create a game like Magic: The Gathering where no such gaming system previously existed.)*

However, this doesn't present much of an issue in the context of procedural narrative generation in that the most successful literary work in terms of audience/sales tends to be based on pre-existing formulas.  So an AI that can merely reconfigure elements in a formula should be able to generate narratives of interest to the average human.